# In Roslyn, how do I get Document information from SymbolFinder.FindCallersAsync?

Tags: c#, roslyn

What's the right way to find out which `Document` each caller belongs to?
I can't find any property that would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realized I can do `solution.GetDocument()` on `Location.SourceTree`.